# How to resolve sudo error in RHEL7

Tags: rhel, sudo, setuid

I am not able to use sudo, how to resolve this ?

```
$ sudo vi /etc/fstab

sudo: effective uid is not 0, is sudo installed setuid root?
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the error

> sudo: effective uid is not 0, is sudo installed setuid root?

It is clear that the `setuid` is not set for `sudo` command. And also the `user:group` must be `root:root`.

Just become the root user and make sure that it is set. i.e.

```
su -
chown root:root /usr/bin/sudo
chmod u+s /usr/bin/sudo
```

It will set the `setuid` for the `sudo` command.

Comment: This could potentially be a symptom of something more serious. The user should investigate why the sudo executable had the wrong permissions and/or ownership.

Comment: @Kusalananda yeah right, but that will require more info, like when this behaviour started?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is due to  changes in the  permissions of directory /usr/bin.

To resolve this :

1) First be sure that root is owner of this directory /usr/bin :

```
 chown root:root /usr/bin
```

2) and change permission for this file :

```
 chmod u+s /usr/bin/sudo
```